# Plot rolling forecast intraday time series custom interval

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I would like to plot the historic forecasts of intraday 30 min data form the SPY. Data is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2877944/spy.Rdata).

I first plot the forecast fitted from a time window of the last 10 days. h= 13 is the number of 30 minute intervals on a trading day.

```
require(forecast)
a.win  <- window(spy.close,start = end(spy.close)[1]-10*1440*60,end =end(spy.close)[1])
a.fit  <- auto.arima(a.win)  
a.pred <- forecast(a.fit, h=13)
plot(a.pred, type="l", xlab="period", ylab="price",
     main="Overlay historic forecasts & actual prices")
```

Then I shift the 10 day window for one day 5 times, fit the model, and plot the forecasted mean on each run of the loop.

```
for (j in seq(1, 5, by=1)) {   ## Loop to overlay early forecasts 
  result1 <- tryCatch({
    b.end   <- end(spy.close)[1]-j*1440*60 ## Window the time series  
    b.start <- b.end[1]-10*1440*60
    b.window <- window(spy.close, start=b.start, end=b.end)

    b.fit  <-auto.arima(b.window) 
    b.pred <- forecast(b.fit, h=13)
    lines(b.pred$mean, col="green", lty="dashed" )
  }, error = function(e) {return(e$message)} ) ## Skip Errors
}
```

But something is messing up the time axis. So I figured that the problem is that the data is irregular (trading hours from 9.30 to 16, weekends markets are closed), but I could not find a suitable solution (even in the forecast package doc there is no mention of intraday time intervals). Hope that someone can help...